# Open valued and lsc correspondence

Tags: general-topology, continuity

If $F$ is a correspondence which is open-valued and lower semicontiuous, then Graph of $F$ is open.

This is what I tried so far;

Given any point $(x,y)$ in Graph $F$, I am trying to find a neighborhood $U$ of $(x,y)$ such that $U$ is included in Graph $F$. Given that F$(x)$ is open and $y$ is in $F(x)$, there exist a nbhood $V$ of $y$ such that $V$ is included in $F(x)$. I am stuck and I do not know how to construct the nbhood $U$ of $(x,y)$. How can we proceed with a formal proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a counterexample: define $F:\mathbb{R}\to 2^{\mathbb{R}}$ by $F(0)=\mathbb{R}$ and $F(x)=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ if $x\ne 0$. The graph of $F$ is not open, since $(0,0)$ is a non-interior point of the graph.

On the other hand, for every open set $W\subset \mathbb{R}$ the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R} : F(x)\cap W\ne \varnothing\}$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$, hence open. By the [definition](https://mathoverflow.net/a/131209), this means $F$ is lower semicontinuous.